# ThinkTecture Identity Model Get User based on Token

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, token, thinktecture-ident-model

I am using the sweet Indentity Model library from Thinktecture.  I looked high and low and am probably about to ask a dumb question.  Basically, we have a Web Forms application which I am adding ASP.net Web api capabilities to it.  I installed the Identity code samples and gleened what I think I needed to get it working for session token I am able to get a token and send back on future calls but in my API controller the user object does not seem to be set.  I had assumed the framework would interrogate the token if provided and automatically set the Principal based on the token data and mark principal as authenticated?  Is this an invalid assumption and is this something that I must set myself?

Basically I am using the token for Authorization and Authentication but need to pull off UserID from the token/session for additional business rules.

Again if dumb question feel free to haze me.  I am testing using Unit Test if that has any impact on any recommendations.

Code from Unit Test:
1) Get Token, successfully validates user using our business logic and returns token successfully:

```
    private string GetToken(string username, string password)
    {
        Uri _baseAddress = new Uri(Thinktecture.Samples.Constants.WebHostBaseAddress);

        var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = _baseAddress };
        client.SetBasicAuthentication(username, password);

        var response = client.GetAsync("token").Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var tokenResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var json = JObject.Parse(tokenResponse);
        var token = json["access_token"].ToString();
        var expiresIn = int.Parse(json["expires_in"].ToString());
        var expiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(expiresIn);
        return token;

    }
```

2) HTTP HELPER METHOD:

```
 private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post<T>(string path, T data, string Token)
    {           
        //var handler = new HttpClientHandler {};

        //using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Token))
            {
                client.SetToken("Session", Token);
                //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Session", Token);
            }
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/");
            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(path, data);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Throw on error code. 
            return response;
        }
    }
```

3) Calling Code:

```
string Token = GetToken("UserName", "Password"); 

       removed proprietry code here....
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> result = Post<GetCustomerDetailsRequest>("api/Account/GetCustomerProfile", GetCustomerDetailsRequest, Token);
```

Comment: How do you setup the identity from the token for a unit test?

Comment: In my solution I have many projects, one being a Unit Test project and the other a web application.  In the Unit tests I am using the httpclient which calls the token endpoint from the website that the web application defines. I am getting the token back and then trying to make another call to a different route with the token and wondering if supplying the token is all I need to do be considered Authenticated and have access to the Principal?

Comment: And how are you passing the token to the second call?

Comment: I updated for sample of coding, I guess my first question is whether I need to re-authorize user using token for the Principal to be set or does the Identity stuff handle that for me...

Comment: What is SetToken on HttpClient? A custom extension method?

Comment: "Basically I am using the token for Authorization and Authentication but need to pull off UserID from the token/session for additional business rules." - Where do you need to do that - on the server or on the client? Have you used the claims authentication manager in AuthenticationConfiguration to add your id?